# working with Region of interest in Omnet++ ( veins)

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am working with simple scenario application using veins. I want to compute
different measurements. I used realistic map using SUMO, and the trips of vehicles are generated randomly using randomTrips.py.

I think that the results are not accurate since the measurement (ex: packet delivery probability) should be computed for the vehicles that are in the same area or range, not exist in different area.

Based on my reading:
1- I have to use  O/D Matrices, however, I don't want to back again to sumo
2- configuring a "Region of Interest (ROI)" for the TraCIScenarioManager.

My question: 
How I can specify rectangular area as ROIs and only vehicles in these areas will be simulated in OMNeT++, from which file I have to change?

thank you in advanced

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is what you want, but the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35334196/using-a-subset-of-a-sumo-scenario-for-omnet-network-simulation-with-veins) might help you along

Comment: Thank you for your help, I found the answer of my question in your post, by using RoiRect .

Comment: Maybe, you want to post your solution to the question as a dedicated answer here, such that the question will be marked answered and hence be more effective for helping people with a similar problem.